# Facing grok filter issue

Tags: elastic-stack, grok

```
Response :  "timestamp":"2023-04-21T06:27:06.255+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/logs" 
 
Grok filter : (?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601})\s+%{NUMBER:response_code}\s+%{DATA:error}\s+%{DATA:path}

also treid :  (?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601})\,+%{NUMBER:response_code}\,+%{DATA:error}\,+%{DATA:path}
```

I am facing issue to create filter for my response , Please suggest .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

`"timestamp":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}","status":%{NUMBER:status:int},"error":"%{DATA:error}","path":"%{DATA:path}"`

Comment: Worked !! thanks Ankit

Comment: If it worked for you, you should select this as answer.